# Google Maps API for Time and Distance Data (Access/VBA)

Tags: google-maps, ms-access, google-api, vba

I have an application where it would be highly beneficial to be able
to get directly from google maps the time and miles (driving miles)
between two addresses. I have plowed through many web sites and
documents and totally foxed as to how to do it.

Has anyone made a successful connection with google maps API using
Microsoft Approach  and extracted time and distance information? If
have, o could they share the code they used.

I am trying to set up a driver scheduling system for a volunteer
drivers group (driving for people wo medical appointments who cannot
drive, cannot afford taxies and  cannot afford cars!).

Any help would be appreciated

John Baker

Answer (score 8):

Here's some code to do what you want to do. Do realize that Google does have some licensing requirements/limitations on using their API. You are supposed to use the results obtained here in a Google Map. Please read the Usage Limitations here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Note that this requires a reference to "Microsoft XML, v6.0" unless you change the code to use late binding.

```
Dim sXMLURL As String
sXMLURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=NY,+NY&destination=Los+Angeles,+CA&sensor=false"

Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP
Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP

With objXMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", sXMLURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .Send
End With

'Debug.Print objXMLHTTP.ResponseText

Dim domResponse as DOMDocument60
Set domResponse = New DOMDocument60
domResponse.loadXML objXMLHTTP.ResponseText
Dim ixnStatus
Set ixnStatus = domResponse.selectSingleNode("//status")

If ixnStatus.Text = "OK" Then
    Dim ixnDistance, ixnDuration
    Set ixnDistance = domResponse.selectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/distance/text")
    Set ixnDuration = domResponse.selectSingleNode("/DirectionsResponse/route/leg/duration/text")

    Debug.Print "Distance: " & ixnDistance.Text 'Miles
    Debug.Print "Duration: " & ixnDuration.Text 'Days Hours Minutes
End If

Set domResponse = Nothing
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
```

I've intentionally chosen to use XML instead of JSON because VBA is not overly handy with JSON, and neither am I. There is a module you can download often referred to as VBJSON but it has a little learning curve, especially if you never worked with JSON before. I believe XML is more "expensive" (less efficient) but I think it's also easier to work with in Access VBA.

Comment: sMapURL was an artifact. :) I've removed it.