# How to Google the street address and return the value back into Excel using Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, google-places-api

I have a list of over 50,000 places in Excel (eg. Arches National Park, Cornell Museum of Glass). When I type "Cornell Museum of Glass" into Google, it returns an address of "1 Museum Way, Corning, NY 14830". I need the full street address **Street #, Street name, and postal code**. I do have the state NY though(in Excel). Does anyone know how to search the address on Google(typing Cornell Museum of Glass), then return the street address back onto Excel(1 Museum Way, Corning, NY 14830)? I know VBA is capable of doing this, and I don't want to manually do it 50,000 times, plus I'm a total newbie at VBA. If anyone knows how I would greatly appreciate it! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are the addresses in Excel along with the places? It looks like you're saying that your Excel file has the addresses already.

Comment: You should check the google search API but the number of searches you can do per day might be limited. Alternatively you can use internet explorer (or chrome via Selenium) automation and scrape the HTML returned but this is likely to be a laregly unreliable/unstable solution.

Comment: Isn't it "Corning Museum of Glass" and not "Cornell..." ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should be the information needed to solve the problem

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116301/google-maps-api-for-time-and-distance-data-access-vba) is a post that shows how to use VBA and XML to interact with Google Maps (via the google maps api).
And [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) is google's Place API, which is what you're looking for (requesting/receiving information from google).

**Answer**
I have created a working test. You have to create a google API key, you can go [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_apikeys) to do that. Once you have the API key, put it into the code and run it.

Note that Google does restrict how often an API key can be used each day. A free user seems to get 1000 "requests" to the "place" API each day. Annoyingly, some calls seem to be worth more "requests" than others. My code makes 2 calls to google's "place" API, but google counts them as 11 requests. This is because a call to "place/textsearch" is worth 10 "requests". My other call was to places/details is worth 1. All this means is that you're limited to 90 entries each day/free api key with this method.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search) is Google's place/search documentation
[Here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details) is Google's place/details documentation

Finally, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985887/how-can-i-extract-the-distance-from-google-directions-api-via-excel-web-query) was a terrific post for this topic, I based my code off it.

Test output:

[image]

Code:

```
Sub myTest()
    Dim xhrRequest As XMLHTTP60
    Dim domDoc As DOMDocument60
    Dim domDoc2 As DOMDocument60
    Dim placeID As String
    Dim query As String
    Dim nodes As IXMLDOMNodeList
    Dim node As IXMLDOMNode

    'you have to replace spaces with +
    query = "Cornell+Museum+of+Glass"

    'You must acquire a google api key and enter it here
    Dim googleKey As String
    googleKey = "imaginary api key" 'your api key here

    'Send a "GET" request for place/textsearch
    Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60

    xhrRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?" & _
        "query=Cornell+Museum+of+Glass&key=" & googleKey, False
    xhrRequest.send

    'Save the response into a document
    Set domDoc = New DOMDocument60
    domDoc.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText

    'Find the first node that is called "place_id" and is the child of the "result" node
    placeID = domDoc.SelectSingleNode("//result/place_id").Text

    'recycling objects (could just use new ones)
    Set domDoc = Nothing
    Set xhrRequest = Nothing

    'Send a "GET" request for place/details
    Set xhrRequest = New XMLHTTP60
    xhrRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/xml?placeid=" & placeID & _
    "&key=" & googleKey, False
    xhrRequest.send

    'Save the response into a document
    Set domDoc = New DOMDocument60
    domDoc.LoadXML xhrRequest.responseText

    Dim output As String
    Dim s As String

    'hacky way to get postal code, you might want to rewrite this after learning more
    Set nodes = domDoc.SelectNodes("//result/address_component/type")
    For Each node In nodes
        s = node.Text
        If s = "postal_code" Then
            'this is bad, you should search for "long_name", what i did here was assume that "long_name was the first child"
            output = vbNewLine & "Postal Code: " & node.ParentNode.FirstChild.Text
        End If
    Next node

    'output
    MsgBox "Formatted Address: " & domDoc.SelectSingleNode("//result/formatted_address").Text & output
End Sub
```

'####

EDIT: Now using place API rather than Geocoding API

Comment: the place API says it's java script, does that also work for excel...?P.S. it's really hard to understand what's going on, it's like trying to read hieroglyphics  :(

Comment: I think I see what you mean, it was actually asking you to follow another link if you were making a javascript application. The rest of the page is for XML/JSON, which you can run on VBA. I know what you mean about the hieroglyphs, try to match up the code with the API (taught me a lot, I've never done anything with google's api either xD)

Comment: @Alter
`placeID = domDoc.SelectSingleNode("//result/place_id").Text`
It errors on this line - is there something else that needs to be amended?

Comment: Unsure, that code worked for me. Try making a post with the error, maybe someone can help find it (I no longer use excel/vba)

Answer (score 0):

I had an error similar to a poster above that I fixed and wanted to post the fix somewhere as I am now using a modified version of this code which once it works I will also post.  What was happening is I was passing names that google had no results for.  If you may be in a similar boat the following line is a positive check for if you got something back:  (the negitive is not = "ZERO_RESULTS")

```
if domDoc.selectSingleNode("//status").Text = "OK"
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to get an API key and then the code will work just fine.  Go to the link below and click the button that reads 'GET A KEY'.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial